# Как загрузить fxml в ListView?

Tags: java, android, javafx

```
@FXML
private void initialize(){ // метод нужен для работы
    contactForList.fieldData();// чтобы метод получил данные из коллекции
    contactForList.getContactList()); // нужен что бы ListView мог принимать коллекцию из другого класса
    listContact.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Contact>, ListCell<Contact>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<Contact> call(ListView<Contact> param) {
            //тут нужно собрать объект ListCellContact, и вернуть его
            ListCell<Contact> listCell = new ListCell<Contact>() {

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Contact item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty || item == null) {
                        setText(null);
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        //тут нужно загрузить fxml файл            
                        // пробовал способом ниже , но не получается 

                      FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/boxInContact.fxml"));
                       fxmlLoader.setController(this);

                        labelName.setText(item.getName());
                        lblSense.setText(item.getSense());
                        lblStatus.setText(item.getStatus());
                        avatar.setImage(item.getImage());


                    }
                }
            };
            return listCell;
        }
    });
    listContact.setItems((ObservableList) contactForList.getContactList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы сделали почти все верно, только не достали рута из загруженной fxml

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Contact item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (empty || item == null) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        //тут нужно загрузить fxml файл            
        // пробовал способом ниже , но не получается 
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/boxInContact.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        labelName.setText(item.getName());
        lblSense.setText(item.getSense());
        lblStatus.setText(item.getStatus());
        avatar.setImage(item.getImage());
        setGraphic((Node) fxmlLoader.getRoot()); // добавьте эту строчку
    }
}
```

Но могу сразу сказать, что у вас будет подгружаться `fxml'ка` всегда при вызове `updateItem`, а это происходит довольно часто ( при скроле, например), в связи с этим возможны подвисания приложения, т.к. вы загружать fxml будете в том же потоке. Поэтому, советую рассмотреть какие-нибудь альтернативы.